# Connection being made, but content is unable to be retrieved from web service

Tags: blackberry

```
public class ConsumeFactoryThread extends Thread {
    private String url;
    private HttpConnection httpConn;
    private InputStream is;
    private CustomMainScreen m;
    private JSONArray array;

    public ConsumeFactoryThread(String url, CustomMainScreen m){
        System.out.println("Connection begin!");
        this.url = url;
        this.m = m;
    }

    public void finished(){
        m.onFinish(array);


    }

    public void run(){

        myConnectionFactory connFact = new myConnectionFactory();
        ConnectionDescriptor connDesc;

        connDesc = connFact.getConnection(url);
        System.out.println("Connection factory!");
        if(connDesc != null)
        {
            System.out.println("Connection not null!");
            httpConn = (HttpConnection) connDesc.getConnection();
            is = null;



            try
            {
                final int iResponseCode = httpConn.getResponseCode();
                UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable()
                {

                    public void run()
                    {
                        System.out.println("Connection in run!");
                         // Get InputConnection and read the server's response
                        InputConnection inputConn = (InputConnection) httpConn;
                        try {
                            is = inputConn.openInputStream();
                            System.out.println("Connection got inputstream!");
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        byte[] data = null;
                        try {
                            data = IOUtilities.streamToBytes(is);
                            System.out.println("Connection got data!");
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }



                        String result = new String(data);
                        System.out.println("Connection Data: "+result);
                        try {
                            array = new JSONArray(result);

                            //finished();

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }


                    }

                });
            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {
                System.err.println("Caught IOException: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }

    }

}
```

I'm using the blackberry torch 9800 simulator and hardware device for testing. 
In the simulator I cannot retrieve the data over wifi, even though the connection to wifi is found. It works when the mobile network is enabled.

Now, when I replace my web service with the Twitter api, I get the data regardless of transport type. I tried adding ;deviceside=false to my url, but nothing. It's not https or anything.

I just want my web service accessed! I know nothing about this mds,bis,bes,bis_b junk.

EDIT:

Jeez. I'm realizing it may be my site. Not using the web service and just retrieving the page, www.example.com, I get nothing. But, google.com or any other site I use retrieves the html. Am I missing headers!?!

Answer (score 0):

Try appending `;interface=wifi` to the end of your URL, this will force the simulator to use your simulated Wi-Fi connection, which is your PC's network connection.

You will need to have setup Wi-Fi on the simulator by going to `Manage Connections->Set Up Wi-Fi Network`, then connect to `Default WLAN Network`.

Comment: it's not a connection problem. It's getting the internet connection, however there is no data being returned for my site only. I transferred the site to another host and it works! Now, my problem is explaining to the IT guy that it is not connecting only through the blackberry. I can get to it through a browser etc..

Comment: Are you still having a problem? Consider updating your question if the problem has changed.

Comment: I haven't. All websites work except for mine. Could it be a firewall? Maybe someone could educate me on how httpconnection works.

Comment: Unfortunately open ended questions like 'explain how httpconnection works' don't work very well on SO. I would update your question to be specific about the problem you are having.